# How to get fileno / filehandle of a socket in C# (dotnetcore)

Tags: c#, c, .net, sockets, .net-core

I am trying to port a python API to c#.
The API itself uses low level api in C.
One of the function accept as parameter a socket file handle.

To get the filehandle, in python, we would do like this:

```
s = socket()
s.fileno()
```

I've tried the following in c#:

```
(int)msock.SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()
//appears to be the same as
(int)msock.Handle
```

However I'm getting an error invalid argument from the function I'm calling.

It might be one of the other arguments, but I'm suspecting the socket...

To have an idea of the complete code:
Working c code (c code is used by python):

```
struct sockaddr_in inaddr;
struct in_addr in;
socklen_t addrlen;
if (inet_pton(AF_INET, ipstr, &in) != 1) {
        return PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "invalid IP address: %s", ipstr);
}
inaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = in.s_addr;
inaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr = (struct sockaddr *)&inaddr;
addrlen = sizeof(inaddr);
maapi_connect(s, addr, addrlen); //The function I am interested
```

My C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sockaddr_in
{
    public short sin_family;
    public ushort sin_port;
    public uint sin_addr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] sin_zero;
};

Socket msock =  new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); //TODO Support for IPv6 etc...
IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
sockaddr_in sin = new sockaddr_in()
{
    sin_family = libconfd_constants.AF_INET,
    sin_port = (ushort)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((short)port),
#pragma warning disable 618
    sin_addr = (uint)ipa.Address,
#pragma warning restore 618
    sin_zero = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
int alen  = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(sockaddr_in));
var r = libconfd_bindings.maapi_connect((int)msock.SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), sin, alen);
```

Any idea ?
Edit: I forgot to mention, this is dotnet core, i'm doing this on my mac

Comment: read the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.safehandle?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: where are you getting the invalid argument

Comment: That's exactly how I were trying to get the handle :).
Basically, r is -1 (error result), so I am calling the function confd_lasterr_string() which gives the last error from the library I am interfacing with. The result is: 
"Failed to connect to ConfD: Invalid argument"

Comment: .NET provides lots of helper classes so you don't need to handle things like sockets directly.  Take a higher level view of your port, don't just try and implement it in a different language.

Comment: I don't think python is using the same socket as c#.  There is a windows socket and a Net socket.  When microsoft created Net they decided that there were know bugs in the Windows Socket object.  And microsoft didn't want to fix windows because there would be an backwards compatibility issue so they create an new socket library for net that isn't compatible with windows.  I think the python socket is the windows library.

Comment: I know, but I have no control on the low end lib I am using, and some functions expect a socket id...

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is dotnet core, i'm doing this on my mac